# Is it possible to pass derived classes by reference to a function taking base class as a parameter

Tags: c++, interface

Say we have an abstract base class `IBase` with pure virtual methods (an interface).

Then we derive `CFoo`, `CFoo2` from the base class.

And we have a function that knows how to work with IBase.

```
Foo(IBase *input);
```

The usual scenario in these cases is like this:

```
IBase *ptr = static_cast<IBase*>(new CFoo("abc"));
Foo(ptr);
delete ptr;
```

But pointer management is better to be avoided, so is there a way to use references in such scenario?

```
CFoo inst("abc");
Foo(inst);
```

where `Foo` is:

```
Foo(IBase &input);
```

Comment: Yes, what you have in your question is ideal.

Comment: Yes; polymorphism works for both pointers and references. And stop casting, please. We're not in Hollywood.

Comment: Now I know why it is called casting... seriously!

Comment: @KerrekSB Well you'd have to cast if you tried `IBase& b = CFoo();`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes.
You don't have to upcast your objects. All references/pointers to derived types are converted implicitly to base objects references/pointers when necessary.

So:

```
IBase* ptr = new CFoo("abc"); // good
CFoo* ptr2 = static_cast<CFoo*>(ptr); // good
CFoo* ptr3 = ptr; // compile error

CFoo instance("abc");
IBase& ref = instance; // good
CFoo& ref2 = static_cast<CFoo&>(ref); // good
CFoo& ref3 = ref; // compile error
```

When you have to downcast you may want to consider using `dynamic_cast`, if your types are polymorphic.

Comment: I found where my problem was. I was using `Foo(CFoo("abc"));` which was not compiling.

Comment: @Coder : In case you're not aware, the reason that's a problem is because you're passing `Foo` an rvalue, and rvalues cannot bind to non-const lvalue references (i.e., if `Foo` were `Foo(IBase const& input);` instead, it would have compiled).

Answer (score 0):

You can cast an object just as you can a pointer. I remember this was common when converting `char` to `unsigned char` and various other sign changing casts in days of yore.