# Apply function to objects of derived class in C++

Tags: c++

In C++, suppose I have a function `dummy(foo& f)` that does some computation on the public members of `f`. Now there is a class `bar` that publicly inherits from `foo`, and `b` is an object of `bar`. Can I call `dummy` on `b`? Or I need to redefine `dummy(bar& b)`? What is the best practice here? Note that the scenario is a bit different from the scenario where virtual function and runtime polymorphism can be applied.

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work or not?

Comment: @eerorika I tried it and it worked, but I still want to understand why.

Comment: @Dai, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: Can you give a small example of what you tried?

Comment: @Chipster my question is answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285627/is-it-possible-to-pass-derived-classes-by-reference-to-a-function-taking-base-cl. You can refer there for concrete examples.