# Creating base class object with a derived class

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
class A {
public:
    A() { cout << "A()" << endl; }
    void f() { cout << "A" << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() { cout << "B()" << endl; }
    void f() { cout << "B" << endl; }
    void ff() { cout << "ff()" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A a = B();
    B b;
    a = b;
}
```

How calling `A a = B();` will be different from `A a = A();`? Why is the conversion from derived class to base class possible?

Comment: `How calling A a = B(); will be different from A a = A();?` During the execution of this line, the `B` constructor will be executed, in addition to `A`. After this line is executed - the objects stored in `a` will be exactly the same due to [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `A a = B();`, copy constructor of class `A` should be invoked after default constructor of class `B` has been invoked (Note: Compiler may remove unnecessary copy using [copy elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)).

```
A(const A& other)
{

}
```

Since, object of class `B` can be passed to copy constructor of class `A`, it will be allowed but you may experience [object-slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

If you are curious to know "*how is it possible to pass a derived class object to a method accepting a reference to the base class*", read the following:

1. [Is it possible to pass derived classes by reference to a function taking base class as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9285652/5735010)